# how to stop propagating event on press of enter in antd date picker input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

how to stop propagating event on press of enter in antd date picker input

I have configured antd date picker as antd column filter using filterdropdown in column configuration . Now on click of enter in antd date picker input the event is getting propagated
and sort is happening in antd table column i want to stop the propagation but was not able to catch the event of pressing enter in antd date picker input how to catch this event and stop this propagation